# Proof that $Y_{t}dX_{t}=dY_{t} \Rightarrow d[Y,Y]_{t}=Y^{2}d[X,X]_{t}$ for continuous semimartingale X?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

An identity, namely: $Y_{t}dX_{t}=dY_{t} \Rightarrow d[Y,Y]_{t}=Y^{2}d[X,X]_{t}$ for continuous semimartingale X, is used rather frequently. I understand that $Y_{t}=e^{X_{t}-X_{0}}$ is the solution for initial value $X_{0}$ but cannot see what can be done from here to prove it directly.

Comment: $d[Y,Y]_t=(dY_t)^2$

Comment: @Zizou23 Thank you so much! I just realized this is even alluded to in the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation#Semimartingales. I presume the proof for this identity ($d[Y,Y]_t=(dY_t)^2$) is similar to https://i.imgur.com/6t8MAr6.png?

Comment: see p.143 of [Stochastic Calculus for Finance II: Continuous-Time Models](https://www.amazon.com/Stochastic-Calculus-Finance-II-Continuous-Time/dp/144192311X)

Comment: @QFi That implies for$X(t)=X(0)+\int_{0}^{t} \Delta(u) d W(u)+\int_{0}^{t} \Theta(u) d u$, it is s.t. $d[X,X]_{t}=\Delta^{2}dt$ for some adapted $\Delta$. Is $\Delta=\frac{dX}{\sqrt{dt}}$ necessarily?